# Installing WineHQ after faulty installation?

Tags: 16.04, wine

I was installing WineHQ version 1.8.4 on my Ubuntu 16.04 by typing

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

into the terminal. After the Microsoft end user agreement showed up, the terminal froze  and wouldn't let me continue, so I had to close the terminal. Now when I try to do `sudo apt-get install wine` again it won't work, telling me:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) 
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

How can I install wine now? Should I uninstall what I had done and try again - if so, how would I uninstall it?, and is uninstalling safe to do?

Comment: Try rebooting and see what happens.